# Cannot render swig templates in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swig-template

So I'm trying to use [consolidate.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js) to render [swig templates](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig) with express, but I get the following error when I try to "extend" one template from another:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '//one.html
```

In my `app.js` file I setup swig as my rendering engine (only including relevant code):

```
var consolidate = require('consolidate');

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('.html', consolidate.swig);

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.render('two');
});
```

And I have a base template, `one.html`:

```
<h3>My Site</h3>
{% block content %}
    Welcome
{% endblock %}
```

Then an inheriting template, `two.html`:

```
{% extends 'one.html' %}

{% block content %}
    This is an inner page.
{% endblock %}
```

So why does swig look for `one.html` with a path of `//one.html` (like in the error above?) Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out after looking at the swig documentation (specifically the [section on usage with Express](http://paularmstrong.github.com/swig/docs/#api-express).) All I had to do was initialize swig, and tell it where to look for "extended" templates:

```
var consolidate = require('consolidate'),
    swig = require('swig');

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('.html', consolidate.swig);

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.render('two');
});

/* Tell swig where to look for templates when one extends another. */
swig.init({ root: __dirname + '/views' });
```

Comment: you dont need to use consolidate, just [use `swig.renderFile`as engine](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/#express) => `app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);`

Comment: Note that `swig.init` is deprecated in the latest version of swig For additional options see the [swig documentation](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/api/#SwigOpts)