# Openshift Failed to load c++ bson extension / Cannot find module ('swig')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, swig, openshift

I am trying to get my node/mongo/express app working on Openshift. It works locally, but on Openshift I am getting an Error: Cannot find module ('swig') I have added it to my dependencies in the package.json as shown below.

```
"dependencies": {
"bcrypt-nodejs": "~0.0.3",
"consolidate": "~0.9.1",
"express": ">=3.x",
"mongodb": "~1.3.9",
"swig": "~0.14.0",
"validator": "~1.1.3"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"bundleDependencies": [],
```

And I require it in my server.js like so:

```
var swig = require('swig'); var cons = require('consolidate'); 
//later app.engine('html', cons.swig);
```

The Full Error reads:

```
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Current directory: /var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/app-root/runtime/
repo

/var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/m
ongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:378
          throw err
                ^
Error: failed to connect to [127.9.214.2:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/app-root/ru
ntime/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:553:74)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/app-root/ru
ntime/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15
)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/app-root/
runtime/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:512:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:426:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8

DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
changed
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Current directory: /var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/app-root/runtime/
repo
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
Express server listening on port 8080

module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'swig'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/app-root/
runtime/repo/server.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8

DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
```

Is this a problem with the Failure to load c++ bson extension, that is causing these other errors? Is there a way around this problem? It works fine locally, just not on openshift.
Thanks in advance for your help!

---

I re-installed my node-modules folder by deleting it and running npm install and that fixed the Cannot find module ('swig') Error, however, now I am getting an error that it cannot find the module '../helpers', which seems to be a folder that should exist inside of swig within the node-modules folder. I ran a search for where it is being included and this is what I got:

```
Searching 744 files for "../helpers"

C:\Repositories\meanapps\node_modules\swig\lib\tags\else.js:
    1: var helpers = require('../helpers'),
    2    _ = require('underscore');
    3  

C:\Repositories\meanapps\node_modules\swig\lib\tags\filter.js:
    1: var helpers = require('../helpers'),
    2    _ = require('underscore');
    3  

C:\Repositories\meanapps\node_modules\swig\lib\tags\for.js:
    1: var helpers = require('../helpers'),
    2    _ = require('underscore');
    3  

C:\Repositories\meanapps\node_modules\swig\lib\tags\if.js:
    1: var helpers = require('../helpers'),
    2    _ = require('underscore');
    3  

C:\Repositories\meanapps\node_modules\swig\lib\tags\import.js:
    1: var helpers = require('../helpers'),
    2    _ = require('underscore');
    3  

C:\Repositories\meanapps\node_modules\swig\lib\tags\include.js:
    1: var helpers = require('../helpers'),
    2    _ = require('underscore');
    3  

C:\Repositories\meanapps\node_modules\swig\lib\tags\set.js:
    1: var helpers = require('../helpers'),
    2    _ = require('underscore');
```

Could this be because I am using an incorrect version of swig?

Ok, fixed that error by making sure they were added through git to openshift. Now, I get this and I have no idea what it is looking for:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '//layout.html'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
    at getSingle (/var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/app-root/runtime/r
epo/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:152:19)
    at get (/var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/app-root/runtime/repo/no
de_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:159:7)
    at Object.exports.compileFile (/var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/a
pp-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:174:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/app-root/
runtime/repo/node_modules/swig/lib/parser.js:346:33)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/ap
p-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at Object.precompile (/var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/app-root/r
untime/repo/node_modules/swig/lib/parser.js:324:7)
    at Object.compile (/var/lib/openshift/52fda83ee0b8cd07040001cb/app-root/runt
ime/repo/node_modules/swig/lib/parser.js:425:18)
```

Comment: I might suggest completely deleting your node_modules folder and re-fetching it using 'npm install'.  On occasions I've also had to run 'npm cache clean' when I've had strange npm issues.  Also since you've had issues installing a native module, you might want to look into whether you have gcc installed.

Comment: Hey that fixed the Cannot find module 'swig' error! Now I am getting a different, but related error that I will update above. Thanks!

Comment: I think my problem now is that swig requires fs. I have tried to install fs using npm install fs, but it responds that it is not in the npm registry. Do you think this might be the problem, and if so how do I install fs if it is not in the registry?

Comment: fs is a core node.js module - you don't install it via npm, its just 'there'.  What version of node.js are you using?

Comment: and fs is clearly there, as the error is being thrown by fs.openSync.  It looks like swig is trying to read a file at the location '//layout.html' which is an invalid filename/path on any OS.

Comment: I think I found the answer to your problem, which relates to how you are initializing swig - I added this to an answer.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first part of your problem is some sort of corrupted module - perhaps due to gcc not being installed, but maybe not.

My suggestion is to wipe your node modules, and npm cache and re-acquire the modules using:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Once you did this, you experienced problems opening a file '//layout.html'

This seems to be a known problem, resolved by [initializing swig and to tell it where to find the template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13907921/832390).

Comment: It worked!! Thank you very much! I have gcc installed on my computer and added to path, but I think that error is something that needs to be resolved on openshift. On the openshift forum I was referred here https://www.openshift.com/content/c-bson-extension-using-pure-js-version#comment-39405 for that error. But it doesn't seem to be causing any serious issues now, the other errors are resolved and the app runs like a charm! Thanks again!